# JSONPath Expression with deep filter

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given the following JSON Array

```
[
 {
  "id":1, 
  "list":[
    {"id":1,"type":{"ref":1,"tema":3}},
    {"id":2,"type":{"ref":1,"tema":6}}
  ]
 },...
]
```

Using a jsonPath expression, how can I get all the list elements with type.ref==1?
I could not find a filter with 2 levels in all the examples I found with Google.

Comment: which programming language? c#, java, turbo pascal?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I'm searching for a jsonPath expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this

```
$..list[?(@.type.ref == 1)]
```

or that

```
$..list..type[?(@.ref == 1)]
```

should do.

Comment: This seems logical and I tried it before, but it does not work. It looks like using more than 1 level after @ does not work.

Comment: in which environment (or evaluator) did you test it?

Comment: I'm using Spring Web MVC 3.2.3 and Jayway JSONPath 0.8.1

Comment: i've evaluated `$..list..type[?(@.ref == 1)]` and it's evaluating correctly [here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) and [there](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/). but it fails [here](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: Your first link uses Jayway 1.2, the last one uses versions up to 0.8.3 and I'm using 0.8.1. I will try to update my version.

Comment: i couldn't find any online jsonpath evaluation tool (except curiousconcept.com... but i think there's a bug...) that uses v0.8.1.

Comment: Well... I can not update my version of json-path without updating spring-test dependency version... But your second filter works on recent version of json-path. Thanks!